# Are smaller subnets more efficient (when routing to/from)?

Tags: subnet

Say I have 4 IPs in a subnet.

**Scenario 1 (/24):**

```
Client A: 10.0.0.1/24
Client B: 10.0.0.2/24
Client C: 10.0.0.3/24
Client D: 10.0.0.4/24
```

**Scenario 2 (/16):**

```
Client A: 10.0.1.1/16
Client B: 10.0.2.1/16
Client C: 10.0.3.1/16
Client D: 10.0.4.1/16
```

Scenario 2 allows for a bit more logical organization so I would rather use that. The broadcast traffic is going to be the same for both subnets.

**So which is more efficient?**

What do I mean by efficient? Lower latency, more throughput, etc.

Intuition tells me that they should be exactly the same, but experience tells me that there might be cases where **routers** can make more efficient calculations when certain things are true (e.g. smaller number of bits can change.) Is my intuition correct? Does it only apply when the network pipe is 99% utilized?

**Edit:**

Some clarification... I am using the term switch loosely to apply switch hardware in general (i.e. could actually be a router.) - My mistake.

What this particular subnet would be used for is routing packets. I have several campuses that would be connected to this subnet to route between each other.

So perhaps the real question should be: is routing packets into/out of a smaller subnet more efficient than a larger one?

Comment: False dichotomy.  Which is more deadly - getting shot in the brainstem by a .45 caliber bullet, or getting shot in the brainstem by a .50 caliber bullet?

Comment: @HopelessN00b I fail to see how that applies...

Comment: `So which is more efficient? What do I mean by efficient? Lower latency, more throughput, etc.` - Neither. The ip addressing scheme has nothing to do with latency or throughput. `experience tells me that there might be cases where switches can make more efficient calculations when certain things are true (e.g. smaller number of bits can change.)` - Switches don't make any calculations based on the ip address. Switches (in the strict term) are layer 2 devices and don't know nor care about layer 3.

Comment: I think the sole interest here for you is ease of management if you run out of available subnets or fill one.

Comment: a) Switches don't care for subnet masks. b) Do you have any reliable example or experience where something like this ever *really* mattered?

Comment: Please see my updated question about switch vs. router (I used "switch" loosely). @SvW I have a background in math and did some computer algorithm work. One example is certain types of matrices could have operations performed on them much quicker if certain conditions were met. There were several areas like this were optimizations can be made if certain conditions were met. I don't know about this case though. That's why asked this question.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a valid question with a factual answer (not based on opinon.)

Comment: @joeqwerty the ip addressing scheme **does** impact latency and throughput in routers. Every router out there is going to perform computation on IP packets that specifically deal with the IP part. If one vendor has a poor (slow) algorithm compared to another in their router then latency would increase and throughput would decrease. In the same vein what I'm asking is, in general, can this "computation" make some optimizations for smaller subnets that make the computation faster (less latency/more throughput)?

Comment: My comment was addressing your specific statement regarding switches. I saw your later comments about routers so I get what you're after. I deal in absolutes. If someone says `switch` then that's layer 2. If someone says `router` then that's layer 3. Layer 3 switches can perform both layer 2 and 3 functions but it's important to make the distinction between the two in your question. So again, what bearing does your layer 3 configuration have on a switch? None at layer 2 when your switch is performing layer 2 functions. Some at layer 3 when your layer 3 switch is performing layer 3 functions.

Comment: @joeqwerty I agree completely. At work I call them all switches because most people think of their wireless router at home when you say router and don't know the difference. When writing my question I didn't even think about it until all the responses I got. By the time I clarified, my question had been downvoted into oblivion, so I probably won't ever get an answer. Oh well...

Comment: Hopefully you'll get some more answers.

Comment: CIDR has been around for more than 20 years. It's not likely that any routers are left on the Internet that might have issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

IP is a Layer-3 addressing scheme, so your subnet layout will only matter for routers. Switches work on Layer-2 and do not deal with IP addresses at all. In Short, a workstation wanting to contact another IP will do a bitwise comarison of netmask and local subnet address. When this results in a local address (your target), an ARP broadcast for that address is sent to all hosts on this Layer-2 segment. The target machine answers with its MAC address and the first machine is able to establish communications.

So you should layout your subnets according to organization structure. Bear in mind, that one day you might want to establish routing, where "greater" address space may help, but maybe some day you will need additional address space for new purposes, so you don't want to "pollute" local networks with too few hosts each.

Comment: It bears mentioning that some switches do in fact operate at layer three, providing routing services when desired.  That being said, it shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: @Gene correct, and that's what I meant actually (see my updated question.)

Comment: Can't cite any proof, but IMHO subnet size should not matter for routing, but - starting from a certain point - the size of your routing table will. For each routing decision, the router has to scan the table for the "longest matching prefix" of route entries. OTOH, with a routing table of 4-16 subnets, I wouldn't expect any performance differences on today's routing hardware ;-)